# Criar Script para copiar link de produtos em um catálogo

Tags: script, automatização

Bom dia.

Eu trabalho em uma empresa onde precisamos fazer um redirect de link de produtos, basicamente o que temos que fazer é ir em um catálogo de produtos (https://prnt.sc/yufxg0) apertar com o botão direito nos cards ir em "copiar link" e colar em um bloco de notas/planilha etc, é um processo muito repetitivo, e estou pensando em desenvolver algum script para automatizar esse processo, alguma idéia de linguagem, ou material para começar a desenvolver isso?

Quando a gente inspeciona o card, existe um padrão, dentro de duas divs especificas tem o link que eu preciso. (https://prnt.sc/yui8e3)
Obrigado.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Olá, amigo acredito que isso pode ter ajudar:

http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2018/05/23/processando-html-para-pegar-informacoes-de-controles/

Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui desenvolver uma boa parte do programa utilizando esse HtmlAgilityPack.

Abraço